# Filter array by sub element that starts with string

Tags: php

How can I filter an array when a sub element starts with a certain string? This will filter results when 'name' matches 'bk-' but how can I alter it so matched elements starting with 'bk-' instead?

```
$starts_with = 'bk-';

$new_facets = array_filter($facets, function ($var) use ($starts_with) {
    return ($var['name'] == $starts_with);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like [substr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) will do the job, for example:

```
<?php
$starts_with = 'bk-';

$facets = [
    ['name' => 'bk-0001'],  
    ['name' => 'bk-0002'], 
    ['name' => 'bx-0001']
];

$new_facets = array_filter($facets, function ($var) use ($starts_with) {
    return substr($var['name'], 0, strlen($starts_with)) === $starts_with;
});

print_r($new_facets);
```

https://3v4l.org/G0bHI

**Result:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => bk-0001
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => bk-0002
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the function logic:

```
$new_facets = array_filter($facets, function ($var) use ($starts_with) {
    return (substr($var['name'],0, 3) == $starts_with);
});
```